# Unknown Adobe After Effects plugins

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, plugins

How can I make effects like the ones in the video? Can anyone tell me where I can find the names of the plugins to make these effects?

Comment: The answer to your question is almost certainly "After Effects" but that's not a good enough answer for a StackExchange site.  I don't know enough about warp, turbulence, vortex, etc., to tell you precisely how these effects were made.  But I'm sure AfterEffects was involved.

Answer (score 1):

The animations could be pre-rendered video's edited in the final movie, but the animations are probably made with a plugin in Adobe After Effects as listed above.

I could not identify all of the plugins, but you can start off with the ["Particle"](https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/) plugin used for the particles coming from her fingers.

Comment: And to match the particle source with the fingers you'd use the motion tracker tool.

Comment: is the program for free?